# API returns array of objects when retrieving all records but only a single object when filtering

Tags: arrays, reactjs, api, mern

First of all I am very new to all this. I have a simple CRUD MERN stack app that outputs an unordered list of entries from a database using .map. I am trying to implement a input box that can be used to filter the list based on a parameter. Everything works fine when all results are retrieved however when only 1 result is retrieved I am getting an error that .map is not a function.

```
TypeError: missions.map is not a function
MissionsList.render
src/Components/missionList.js:121
  118 | <p>All data is test data only</p>
  119 | 
  120 | 
> 121 | <ul className="list-group">
      | ^  122 |   {missions.map((mission, index) => (
  123 |       <li
  124 |         className={
View compiled
▶ 18 stack frames were collapsed.
(anonymous function)
src/Components/missionList.js:77
  74 | searchMsn() {
  75 |   MissionDataService.get(this.state.searchMsn)
  76 |     .then(response => {
> 77 |       this.setState({ missions: response.data });
     | ^  78 |       console.log(response.data);
  79 |     })
  80 |     .catch(e => {
```

Looking at the console I can see that the API is working and I can see when all results are retrieved I am getting back an array of objects and when I only retrieve one result I am getting back just an object. I know that this is why it is breaking because .map only works for arrays but I dont know how to fix it.

**Here is the code for the input box and the functions called**

```
    <div className="input-group mb-3">

      <input
        type="text"
        className="form-control"
        placeholder="Search by Msn Number"
        value={searchMsn}
        onChange={this.onChangeSearchMsnNumber}
      />

      <div className="input-group-append">

        <button
          className="btn"
          type="button"
          onClick={this.searchMsn}
        >
          Search
        </button>

      </div>
    </div>

  retrieveMissions() {
    MissionDataService.getAll()
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ missions: response.data });
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  }

  searchMsn() {
    MissionDataService.get(this.state.searchMsn)
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ missions: response.data });
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  }

  onChangeSearchMsnNumber(e) {
    const searchMsn = e.target.value;
    this.setState({
      searchMsn: searchMsn
    });
  }
```

**Here is the http.get code**

```
   get(msnNumber) {
      return http.get(`/missions/${msnNumber}`);
    }
```

Here is the API side of the code

```
router.get('/:msnNumber', function(req, res, next) {
  Mission.findOne({msnNumber: req.params.msnNumber}, function(err, foundMission){
    if (foundMission) {
      res.send(foundMission);
    } else {
      res.send("No missions matching that mission number were found");
    }
  });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by using Mission.find instead of findOne. It seems that find returns an array of objects even if there is only one result while findOne always just returns an object.